# Tic Tac Toe game in C [help function]

Tags: c

I'm actually trying to do a simple Tic Tac Toe game (a classic..) in C. Everything is OK except one of my function : getPlayerInput. I put it here :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 3
    void getPlayerInput(int player, int *row, int *col, char board[N][N]){

        if(player==1){
            printf("It is player %d turn, please choose an empty space: \n", player);
            scanf("%d %d", row, col);
            if((*row>=1) && (*row<=N) && (*col>=1) && (*col<=N) && (board[(*row-1)][(*col-1)] == '_')){
                board[(*row-1)][(*col-1)]='O';
            }
            while((*row-1)<1 || (*row-1)>N || (*col-1)<1 || (*col-1)>N || (board[(*row-1)][(*col-1)] != '_')){
                    printf("This space is illegal, please choose another: \n");
                    scanf("%d %d", row, col);
                    if((*row>=1) && (*row<=N) && (*col>=1) && (*col<=N) && (board[(*row-1)][(*col-1)] == '_')){
                            board[(*row-1)][(*col-1)]='O';
                    }
            }
        }
        if(player==2){
            printf("It is player %d turn, please choose an empty space: \n", player);
            scanf("%d %d", row, col);
            if((*row>=1) && (*row<=N) && (*col>=1) && (*col<=N) && (board[(*row-1)][(*col-1)] == '_')){
                board[(*row-1)][(*col-1)]='X';
            }
            while((*row-1)<1 || (*row-1)>N || (*col-1)<1 || (*col-1)>N || (board[(*row-1)][(*col-1)] != '_')){
                    printf("This space is illegal, please choose another: \n");
                    scanf("%d %d", row, col);
                    if((*row>=1) && (*row<=N) && (*col>=1) && (*col<=N) && (board[(*row-1)][(*col-1)] == '_')){
                            board[(*row-1)][(*col-1)]='X';
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

---

My problems is with **"This space is illegal, please choose another"**. I tried to do this with a while but it doesn't work.. I don't get it..

When a player enters a bad location (out of the grid or something else), he has to re enter a location.

Any idea to fix that ?

Thanks by advance.

---

**Edit 1 :**

```
void getPlayerInput(int player, int *row, int *col, char board[N][N]){

    if((*row-1)<1 || (*row-1)>N || (*col-1)<1 || (*col-1)>N || (board[(*row-1)][(*col-1)] != '_')){
        printf("This space is illegal, please choose another: \n");
        scanf("%d %d", row, col);
    }

    if(player==1){
        printf("It is player %d turn, please choose an empty space: \n", player);
        scanf("%d %d", row, col);
        if((*row>=1) && (*row<=N) && (*col>=1) && (*col<=N) && (board[(*row-1)][(*col-1)] == '_')){
            board[(*row-1)][(*col-1)]='O';
        }
    }
    if(player==2){
        printf("It is player %d turn, please choose an empty space: \n", player);
        scanf("%d %d", row, col);
        if((*row>=1) && (*row<=N) && (*col>=1) && (*col<=N) && (board[(*row-1)][(*col-1)] == '_')){
            board[(*row-1)][(*col-1)]='X';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What spaces would be illegal? Outside of the board and a square that is already occupied? What exactly 'doesn't work'?

Comment: @Codor This gives me This space is illegal, please choose another, and after that, if I enter a correct space, the program gives me another time : This space is illegal, please choose another, etc..

Comment: Within the two `while` loops, note that the condition is repeated - once for the loop, and inside the loop as its negation, and in addition before the `while` loop. This could be changed, I find it a bit confusing. Furthermore, the 'illegality' of the position does not depend on the active player - the only part that depends on the active player is the character finally written into the board.

Comment: Please edit the code in the question instead of communicating the changes in a comment; comments do not permit multiline code formatting. What happens if you enter a 'legal' position first? Do you encounter a bug then?

Comment: @Codor : look at edit 1, in my first post. Like I said, I just deleted the while and take my condition for the illegal position before the two if (player == 1 and player == 2).

Comment: Please see my answer; I believe I have spotted a bug.

Comment: It can't work the way you edited it, as there is no repetition of the input if it is 'illegal', and the contents of `row` and `col` are read before they are entered.

Comment: Yes of course, I just deleted the while and extracted my condition for the illegal location. I know that I can't put it here like this.

Comment: Actually I didn't mean to just delete the `while` loop. The loop should be kept, but perhaps rearranged.

Comment: There is a lot of repetition in the first version of the code. You should be looking to having multiple functions do the job (taking, for example, player number, the player's piece (`'O'` or `'X'`), maybe the opponents piece). You could also look to improve the error messaging. The error message doesn't distinguish between coordinates out of range and already occupied by opponent or by current player. However, these are refinements — properly written repeatitive code works, but the emphasis is on _properly_ (and the more repetition there is, the harder it is to get it all right).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I will try to correct this a little bit. I'll post some edit after that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a 'one-off' error in the condition; say you enter a 'legal' coordinate where the row is 1. The position gets set, but the `while` loop still gets entered, as `(*row-1)<1` is true; perhaps it should be `*row<1`, which is *not* proper negation. Perhaps the coordinate convention was changed from 0-based to 1-based at some point.

Comment: Ok so, Can I do this without the while maybe ?

Comment: Maybe there is a simpler solution.. What do you think ?

Comment: I suggest trying on the coding before the edit; try first to remove the 'one-off' error.

Comment: Ok I will try (so with the while). Thanks a lot for your help.